# ROS Melodic - GCP Ubuntu 18.04 - Could not connect to Display

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, ros, display

I am a beginner, installed ROS Melodic on GCP Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to run  the below

"rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node"

Got the following error : 
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it is showing, it looks like you need to setup an X-Window environment. You can do so by following the Google Cloud Documentation [1].
Also ensure the application that you are running is having all dependencies satisfied.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine